# WSO2 AS server Error when passing date to create solr date

Tags: web-services, web, web-applications, wso2

I configured the 4 servers , but when I try to add the app server to exlipse , I get this error on the console :

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} - Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Dec 13 21:19:56 GMT+01:00 2015"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to install WSO2 product. Just unzip an run [WSO2_Product]/bin/wso2server  .bat for windows or .sh for linux.

To run them in the same server just, before start, change the offset value inside the [WSO2_Product]/repository/conf/carbon.xml Example:

```
<!-- Ports offset. This entry will set the value of the ports defined below to
 the define value + Offset.
 e.g. Offset=2 and HTTPS port=9443 will set the effective HTTPS port to 9445
 -->
<Offset>1</Offset>
```

In this case the port chage to 9444 and 9764, with the offset = 0 (9443 and 9763)

Comment: thanks for help , I configured the 4 servers , but when I try to add the app server to exlipse , I get this error on the console :

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Dec 13 21:19:56 GMT+01:00 2015"

please any one can help me ?

Comment: This is a new question. Could you ask that as anew question? or edit ur question

Comment: please mark my answer as a solution for your 1er question. :-D

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: This answer is not related to "Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date"

Comment: The question was completely modified from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with WSO2 API Manager 10.0 in CentOS. It's related with the locale used by the JVM that seems to be not supported by the server.

As a workaround, I've solved it changing the region of the JVM adding the next parameter to the JVM in wso2server.sh:

```
 -Duser.region=US \
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the region-Option doesn' work for me. 
I added the following options:

```
-Duser.region=US -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=us
```